# Change jquery menus from click to hover

Tags: jquery, drupal

I have a menu on one of my sites that I am trying to convert from using .click to .hover. I changed .click to .hover and it worked for the hover, but what I want to add is something that retracts the menu when you move away from it.

This is a snippet of the original code:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#block-menu-menu-tea-menu").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-teawares").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-teawares-china").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-japan-teawares").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-tea-blends").hide();
    $("#block-menu-menu-tea-types").hide();
    $("#main-menu .menu-1877 a").show();
    $("#main-menu .menu-1885 a").show();

    $('#main-menu .menu-2397 a').click(function() { //Tea by Country
        $("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries").slideToggle();
        $("#block-menu-menu-teawares").hide();
        $("#block-menu-menu-tea-types").hide();
        $("#block-menu-menu-tea-blends").hide();
        $("#block-menu-menu-japan-teawares").hide();
        $("#block-menu-menu-teawares-china").hide();
        return false;
    });
```

What I want to do is convert clicks to hovers. Not 100% sure how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: $("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries") is the a element ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from jQuery's site, the hover function can accept two callbacks, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave.

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    // do stuff when mouse is over the element
  }, function() {
    // do stuff when mouse is moved away from element
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first calls to hide the elements can be minimized to this

Using the starts with selector ^= [Attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("[id^=block-menu-menu-]").hide();
$("#main-menu .menu-1877 a").show();
$("#main-menu .menu-1885 a").show();
```

For your method as the others said use the callback of handlerOut

```
$('#main-menu .menu-2397 a').click(function() { //Tea by Country
        $("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries").slideToggle();
        $("[id^=block-menu-menu-]").not("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries").hide();
        return false;
    },
  function(){
     //Callback handler out
     $("#block-menu-menu-tea-countries").slideToggle();
   }
);
```